# create definition list from json object

Tags: javascript, json, list, structure

I try to create a working json-object structure to create a defintion list.
see what i try to do here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/DzAsa/14/)

```
var x =
[{
    "dl":
    {
        "dt":"head 1"
        {
            "dd":
            [
                "listitem 1",
                "listitem 1",
                "listitem 1",
                "listitem 1",
                "listitem 1"
            ]
        },
       "dt":"head 2"
        {
            "dd":
            [
                "listitem 2",
                "listitem 2"
            ]
        }
    }      
}]
;
```

By executing this snippet of JS I try to create markupt from the JSON object:

```
$.each(x["dl"], function(i,v){
    console.log(this.dt, this.dd);
});
```

Using the variable x I try to create the following markup:

```
<dl>
    <dt>head 1</dt>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>

    <dt>head 2</dt>
    <dd>listitem 2</dd>
    <dd>listitem 2</dd>   
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt>head 1</dt>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>
    <dd>listitem 1</dd>

    <dt>head 2</dt>
    <dd>listitem 2</dd>
    <dd>listitem 2</dd>   
</dl>
```

the markup is what I need to create. What do I do wrong in my JSON structure?

Comment: Please post the code here also. That way it helps the person 2 years from now who's having the same problem.

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you're trying to do. This is not specific enough, and the question may be closed.

Comment: Your object declaration is not valid. The part that says `"dt":"head 1"` is followed immediately by `{`. You need to either follow it with a comma or a `}`.

Comment: Your object isn't valid.  You can't have multiple `dt` properties (the last will overwrite the previous ones).  `"dt":"head 1" {` this isn't valid.

Comment: ok, I tried to change this in Revision 17 of the jsfiddle, but it still does not work, what is still wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this is *not* JSON.  This is just a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of a JavaScript object.

Second, your object isn't correct.  You can't have multiple `dt` properties, I suggest making that an array.  `"dt":"head 1" {` isn't valid.  Also, `x` should be an object, not an array (of an object).

I suggest making your object like this:

```
var x = {
    "dl": [{
        "dt": "head 1",
        "dd": ["listitem 1", "listitem 1", "listitem 1", "listitem 1", "listitem 1"]
    }, {
        "dt": "head 2",
        "dd": ["listitem 2", "listitem 2"]
    }]
};
```

`x` is an object that contains a `dl` property.  `x.dl` is an array containing objects.  Those objects contain `dt` and `dd` properties.

Now your snippet will work correctly:

```
$.each(x["dl"], function(i,v){ // you can also use "x.dl"
    console.log(this.dt, this.dd);
});
```

From this object it's easy to make the HTML you want.

Comment: Rocket, thanks a lot: in Revision 22 of my jsfiddle I got it following your hints. What I did not get right now: What changes would be needed to make the object a JSON object? I often "used" JSON within Ajax requests but never had to build some - I red the documentation but apparently understood wrong.. Greets

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON Object".  JSON is just a string representation of a JavaScript object.  `{a:12}` is an object, `'{"a":12}'` is JSON.  You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert to JSON, and `JSON.parse` to convert to an object.  Depends what you want to do with the object.

Comment: 3 years later.. I just read your last comment :-) and for all those who read it too: there IS THIS THING called JSONObject (not to take it toooo well .. {"a":"12"} ) http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html